# What replacement for play-iteratees?

Tags: playframework

I can see that [play-iteratee](https://github.com/playframework/play-iteratees) is dead although it is still mentioned in Play 2.8 doc. Any idea of a possible replacement? Or maybe no replacement is needed provided that one works with WSClient.stream() ?

Comment: How are you using it? The drop-in replacement is likely Akka Streams.